# Magento 2.1 Pagination not showing

Tags: magento2, pagination

I'm using magento 2.1, and is not showing Prev, Next buttons on category page, I have 200 products, and should show 16 on page, it shows the 16 products but not next, prev buttons, so I can't navigate to other pages, any suggestion to fix this? It does it also with blank or luma theme, so it shouldn't that the problem.

Comment: Is there any custom `view/frontend/templates/html/pager.phtml`?

Comment: the only pager.phtml file I have is in  /public_html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/pager.phtml

Comment: You can take screen shot: current pager category and this admin category?

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you need, is this you're asking for? https://s21.postimg.org/clpu168vb/Immagine.jpg